# How To Assign a Linear System of Equation Answers to An Array

Tags: multidimensional-array, wolfram-mathematica

I have a solution list as below from solving a linear equation system:

```
w[2, 2] -> 0.0000183294,
w[2, 3] -> 0.0000296603,
w[2, 4] -> 0.0000233449,
w[3, 2] -> 0.0000230831,
```

When I call, for example: `w[3,2]` I get `w[3,2]` as output instead of `0.0000230831`.

How can I assign these answers to a 2D array named so `W[i,j]` such that I can call them by their indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution lists are [replacement rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Rules.html) and to get them to work you have to apply the rules. Lets say that you have a [`Solve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) statement that produces your solution list, the following will create a function `W[i,j]` that will return the value of `w[i,j]` if it exists in the list.

```
sol = Solve[...];
W[i_, j_] := w[i, j] /. sol
```

As an aside, you should understand that single brackets `F[i,j,...]` denote a function of the variables i, j, ... and double brackets `F[[i,j]]` denote a 2D array with indexes i and j. In general it is faster and better to use replacement lists to build functions than it is to make arrays out of them.